# Kafka multithreading and routing requests

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-kafka

I  have this platform that has multiple threads and is synchronized by events. Say that there is another thread that once it makes its execution set an event to propagate its decision to a different thread. The alarmed thread checks the events and execute the following code:

```
while not event.is_set():
        if event_new_service_rates.is_set():
            with open(application.name+'.txt', 'r') as f:
                rates = f.readlines()
                for rate in rates:
                    model = rate.split(' ')[0]
                    rate = rate.split(' ')[1]
                    if rate.endswith('\n'):
                        rate = rate[:-1]
                    print('[x] Thread '+str(application.name)+'- Model: '+str(model)+' Rate: '+str(rate))
                    server_to_send[model] = int(float(rate))
                f.close()
            with open(application.name+'.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.truncate(0)
            service_rates = []
            total_rate = 0
            print('[x] Thread '+str(application.name)+'- Server to send: '+str(server_to_send))
            for key , value in server_to_send.items():
                if key.split('_')[0] == application.name:
                    total_rate += value
            if total_rate == 0:
                total_rate = 1
            print('[x] Thread '+str(application.name)+'- Total rate: '+str(total_rate))
            msgs = []
            if application.queue_size != 0:
                server = KafkaConsumer(application.name, bootstrap_servers = [str(ip_address)+':'+str(ip_port)] , client_id =str(application.name), group_id='xxxx', auto_offset_reset='earliest', enable_auto_commit=False , max_poll_records=100 , max_poll_interval_ms=1000)
                print('[x] Thread '+str(application.name)+'- Consumer created')
                print('[x] Thread '+str(application.name)+'- Start Consuming')
                print('[x] Thread '+str(application.name)+'- Consumed '+str(len(msgs))+' messages')
                for msg in server:
                    msgs.append(msg)
                    print('[x] Thread '+str(application.name)+'- Received message number: '+str(len(msgs)))
                    application.queue_size = application.queue_size -1
                    if application.queue_size < 0:
                        application.queue_size = 0
                    if len(msgs) >= total_rate or application.queue_size <= 0:
                        print('[x] Thread '+str(application.name)+'- End Consuming')
                        server.unsubscribe()
                        break   
                print(server_to_send[list_queues[current_model]])
                for msg_to_send in msgs:
                    producer.send(list_queues[current_model], value=msg_to_send.value , key=msg_to_send.key)
                    producer.flush()
                    print('[x] Thread'+ str(application.name)+ '- Message sent to ' + list_queues[current_model])
                    sent_messages += 1
                    print('[x] Thread'+ str(application.name)+ '- Number of messages sent to ' + list_queues[current_model] + ' is ' + str(sent_messages))
                    print(server_to_send)
                    print('[x] Thread'+ str(application.name)+ '- Number of messages to send to ' + list_queues[current_model] + ' is ' + str(int(server_to_send[list_queues[current_model]])))
                    consumed_message += 1
                    print('[x] Thread'+ str(application.name)+ '- Number of messages in the queue: ' + str(application.queue_size))
                    if sent_messages >= int(server_to_send[list_queues[current_model]]):
                        current_model += 1
                        sent_messages = 0
                    if current_model == len(list_queues):
                        current_model = 0
            print('[x] Thread '+str(application.name)+'- Messages in queue: '+str(application.queue_size))
            with open('monitor_resource_'+str(application.name)+'.csv', 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(time.time()-starting_time)+","+str(application.queue_size)+"\n")
            producer.close()
            new_measure_event.set()
            event_new_service_rates.clear()
            service_rates = []
        if event.is_set():
            break
    stop_checking = True
    print('[x] Thread ' + application.name + '- terminated')
```

Long story short, you can see that this thread checks for an event (event_new_serevice_rates), in the case it is set it wants to read a number of messages defined but the sum of the rates of each application and then forward them to other topics based on this rate. The problem is in consuming:

1. The consumer does not subscribe to the group
2. The consumer in this case can be subscribed by using some tricks that I developed, but can not read the correct number of messages requested from the application. The idea is that even if there are more messages it does not mean that I need to read them all, I want to consume the message that my platform can handle.

Could you suggest me a solution to this?

1.Python3 version: 3.8.10

2.Kafka version: 3.2.0

3.Kafka-python version: 2.0.2

Comment: What is `event` or `event_new_service_rates`? What is an example of your text file? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: @OneCricketeer the logic is complex and involves multiple threads and programs. I can tell you that event is used to notify in the case ctrl + c is pressed, in order to return the thread. event_new_service_rates is used by another thread to notify how many messages should be sent by the producer to which specific topic.